# PEAR HTML_Template_IT does not load Templatefile in PHP7

Tags: pear, php-7

I have written a CMS by myself and it works fine until PHP Version 5.6.
Now, PHP7 is starting and I want my CMS get ready for it.
In this CMS I use the PEAR Library, which I have upgraded to Version 1.1o because this version, so is said, supports PHP7.

Now I have following problem with the Package HTML_Template_IT: when trying to load the template file and afterwards setCurrentBlock('meta-tags') I get the message "Cannot find this block"meta-tags'"

Is anybody out there, who had the same problem and could solve it?
thank you so much for your help!

That's my Code in the index.php:

```
require_once('HTML/Template/ITX.php');
$tpl = new HTML_Template_ITX(TEMPLATE_DIR);

// Einlesen der Haupttemplate-Datei
$tpl->loadTemplatefile('main_tpl.html', true, true);

// Meta-Tags ausgeben
$tpl->setCurrentBlock('meta-tags');
$tpl->setVariable('author', AUTHOR);
$tpl->setVariable('description', DESCRIPTION);
$tpl->setVariable('keywords', KEYWORDS);
$tpl->setVariable('page_topic', PAGE_TOPIC);
$tpl->setVariable('publisher', PUBLISHER);
$tpl->setVariable('google_verify', GOOGLE_VERIFY);
$tpl->parseCurrentBlock();
```

here is the corresponding detail from my template-File main_tpl.html:

```
<!-- BEGIN meta-tags -->
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="author" content="{author}" />
<meta name="Content-Language" content="de" />
<meta name="description" content="{description}" />
<meta name="keywords" content="{keywords}" />
<meta name="page-topic" content="{page_topic}" />
<meta name="publisher" content="{publisher}" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="{google_verify}" />
<meta name="rating" content="general" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="10 days" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<!-- END meta-tags -->
```

that's the output in the browser:

```
Cannot find this block"meta-tags'
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution - it works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with getting it to run on PHP 7 is the `e` modifier in its `preg_replace`. You have to replace it near line `1091` in `IT.php`:

```
return preg_replace_callback(
    "#<!-- INCLUDE (.*) -->#im",
    function ($m) { $this->getFile($m[1]); },
    $content
);
```

I don't have PEAR installed on my machine, but it works now given that I commented out `require 'PEAR.php'`. I also changed the constructors to use `__construct` to get rid of the deprecation warnings, those do still work, but will be removed in PHP 8.